# zero's of the " T-zeta function " ? ( $ \zeta_t(s) = \prod_{p = 2}^{\infty} \frac{p^s}{p^s - t}$)

Tags: number-theory, roots, special-functions, perturbation-theory, analytic-continuation

In an old diary I read this :

Consider the following functions :

Let $s,t,v$ be complex.

V-zeta function :

$$ \zeta_v(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s + v} $$

T-zeta function :

$$ \zeta_t(s) = \prod_{p = 2}^{\infty} \frac{p^s}{p^s - t} $$

where $p$ denotes taking the product over the primes.

And we are suppose to consider their behaviour, symmetry , analytic continuations , poles and especially their zero's IN PARTICULAR when $v,t$ are real.

(Notice these are NOT the Hurwitz or Barnes zeta functions !)

Now clearly $\zeta_v(s) = \zeta_t(s) = \zeta(s) $ when $v = 0,t = 1$ so this might be intresting !!
So it is connected to the Riemann zeta function and the Riemann Hypothesis.
I mean if $v,t$ get close to $0,1$ maybe all the nontrivial zero's get very near the critical line ?

As you probably guessed many properties of the riemann zeta function have analogues for the T-zeta function.
In fact the T-zeta function seems easier to understand than the V-zeta function.
For instance clearly the cases $t = r$ and $ t = -r $ are easily related.

It is clear that the individual terms being summed ( $\frac{1}{n^s + v} $) or multiplied ( $\frac{p^s}{p^s - t}$ ) create poles by themselves and at $s = 0$. But one wonders if the functions have nontrivial poles NOT created by these individual terms nor at integer $s$.

One also wonders if these functions can be extended to a meromorphic function on the entire complex plane.
Or maybe we get a natural boundary ? Or a singularity ?

I searched for these functions in the standard literature but found nothing.

However it does remind me of (limits in) perturbation theory.

I have seen perturbation theory used for differential equations, dynamics, calculusn solving polynomials , combinatorics etc but not much for number theory or special functions outside of the above.

But maybe that is just my lack of knowledge.

Have these functions been studied before ?

Is perturbation theory a good idea for these kind of things ?

Plots would be nice to see too.

I assume for $Re(s) > 1,Re(v) > 0,Im(v) = 0$ or $Re(s) > 1,Im(t) = 0$ we get no zero's from the V-zeta or T-zeta function.
( analogue to the prime number theorem proved with the Riemann zeta function )
but maybe I am wrong.

As for perturbation theory I assume these are the 2 most interesting ways to do perturbation on the zeta function , right ??

Answer (score 0):

Just a highlighted comment :

I was thinking about the similar looking function

$$f(s) = \prod_{p = 2}^{\infty} \frac{p^s+1}{p^s - 1} $$

This reminds us of the prime twins by the equivalent

$$f(s) = \prod_{p = 2}^{\infty} 1 + \frac{2}{p^s - 1} $$

Notice

$$(1 + \frac{2}{p^x-1}) =  (1 + \frac{1}{p^x -1})^2 (1 - p^{-2x})$$

We conclude that

$$f(s) = \zeta(s)^2  \prod_p (1- p^{-2s}) = \frac{\zeta(s)^2}{\zeta(2s)}$$

So, $f(s)$ has the same zero's as the Riemann zeta (with multiplicity 2) and at $s=1/2$.