The zeros of $f(s,a) = \sum_{n=1}^{a} (\frac{n^2 + n}{2})^{-s} $
I was looking at the zeros of
$$
f(s,a) = \sum_{n=1}^{a} \Big(\frac{n^2 + n}{2}\Big)^{-s}
$$
for integer $a>3$ in the strip $0 < \operatorname{Re}(s) < \frac{1}{2}$, and of course of the limiting case " triangular zeta function ":
$$
f(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{n^2 + n}{2}\Big)^{-s} 
$$
in the strip $0 < \operatorname{Re}(s) < \frac{1}{2}$.

Of course $f(s)$ has a pole at $s = \frac{1}{2}$ and I am not sure how analytic continuation works beyond there, but just like with the truncated Riemann zeta, where the zeros of them are relevant and converging to the zeros of the Riemann zeta, we get a similar situation here. Well I assume. I'm not sure if analytic continuation to the entire complex plane is possible but I assume that $Re(s) > 0$ and this seems to work fine.

A few observations:

For small $a$ the zeros seem to be somewhat random in the strip $0 < \operatorname{Re}(s) < 1$, while for large $a$ we seem to get some patterns.

For some unbounded function $0 < g(a) < a$ and $s = x + g(a)i$ with $0 < x < \frac{1}{2}$ we seem to get that the zero's of $f(s,a)$ are all the strip  $\frac{1}{3} < \operatorname{Re}(s) < \frac{1}{2}$.

It seems the line $\operatorname{Re}(s) = \frac{1}{3}$ is attracting the zeros for large $g(a)$ but for small imaginary parts it seems it is in fact repelling.
So it seems that the zeros are dense on a curve (looks continuous but like lightning) within $1/3 < \operatorname{Re}(s) < 1/2$ that tends towards the line $1/3$, but is not smooth and is repelled from $1/3$ for small imaginary parts.



I assume the positions of the zeros of $f(s,a)$ converge as $a$ grows or at least the curve they are on does converge to a fixed curve/path.
Questions

Is there a closed form for this curve/path ? (Clarifications would be nice).
Can contour integrals solve this ?


A few further observations:

It seems from observing the behavior of the first zero of $f(s,a)$ that $f(s)$ has a zero with real part $1/3$.

It seems that $f(s)$ has no zero's in the strip $0 < Re(s) < \frac{1}{3}$.

And it might even have a critical line at $Re(s) = \frac{1}{3}$.


Bonus question. Is any of those 3 statements true ?

Ofcourse $f(s)$ has a pole at $s = \frac{1}{2}$ and I am not sure how analytic continuation works beyond there, but just like with the truncated Riemann zeta, where the zero's of them are relevant and converging to the zero's of the Riemann zeta , we get a similar situation here. Well I assume. Im not sure if analytic continuation to the entire complex plane is possible but I assume to $Re(s) > 0$ works fine.

Where the sum for $f$ converges, \begin{align*}
f(s,a) &= \sum_{n=1}^a \left( \frac{n^2 + n}{2} \right)^{-s}  \
&= 2^s\sum_{n=1}^a \frac{1}{(n^2 + n)^{s}}  \
&= 2^s\sum_{n=1}^a \frac{1}{n^s (n + 1)^s}  \text{,}
\end{align*}
putting it in two forms closer to a Dirichlet series.

@Eric this $f$ is a Dirichlet series $\sum c_m/m^s, c_m=1, m=\frac{n(n+1}{2}, c_m=0$ otherwise; also it is easily seen to be $2^s\zeta(2s)+g(s)$ with $g$ analytic in $\Re s >1/3$ but I am not sure about continuation beyond that

note also that the truncated sums of the RZ functions have zeroes in $\Re  s>1$ and the study of their zeroes is only partially understood

note also that the zeroes of $f(s,a)$ cluster at the line $\Re s =1/2$ by a very general classical theorem that states that the zeroes of the Dirichlet partial sums of a convergent Dirichlet series accumulate at the abscissa of the convergence line and which is not that hard to be proven

@Conrad you make some interesting claims and state them as easy provable facts.
But you do not give a link or proof. How do you know $g(s)$ is analytic for $Re(s) > 1/3 $ ? And is $1/3$ optimal ?  And what is known about the zero’s for $Re(s) > 1 $ for $f(s,a)$ and in particular $f(s)$ ? Numerical examples ? Further you mention this clustering of zero’s “ not hard to be proven “ and some  “ general classic theorem “ ?  Care to elaborate ?!

expanding the above in an answer

Mick I've edited you question with some typo fixes and minor formatting: I hope yo don't mind it but if you do, please feel free to rollback my edits.

This is not an answer just a few comments that should help:
Note that writing $$f(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{n^2 + n}{2}\Big)^{-s}=\sum_{m\ge 1}\frac{c_m}{m^s}$$ where $c_m=1$ if $m=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$ and  $c_m=0$ otherwise expresses $f$ as a Dirichlet series with abscissa of absolute convergence (and convergence since $c_m \ge 0$ being $1/2$).
In particular, a classical theorem attributed to Knopp by Jentzsch (see his paper HERE, page $236$) shows that the zeroes of $f(s,a)$ cluster on the line $1/2+it$.
The proof is not difficult considering the analytic functions $g_a(s)=\log f(s,a)/\log a$ in a small neighborhood of a point $1/2+i\tau$ where the zeroes wouldn't cluster and showing that $g_a$ are uniformly bounded (by partial summation since $1/2$ is abscissa convergence) so form a normal family; but for $\Re s >1/2$ in the neighborhood, we have  $g_a(s) \to 0, a \to \infty$ (because $f(s,a)\to f(s)$ there so for a dense open set in the neighborhood where $f$ is not zero we have $\log f(s,a) \to \log f(s)$ finite complex number etc) so by analytic continuation and the above $g_a(s) \to 0$ everywhere in the neighborhood (any subsequence of $g_a$ can only converge to zero and Montel applies to show that any subsequence of $g_a$ has a normally convergent sub-subsequence) and that is easily seen to give a contradiction by considering $\Re s <1/2$ there (using that $\limsup_a \log |\sum_{m \le a} c_m|/\log a=1/2$ by the abscissa definition in terms of coefficients and partial summation we cannot have $\limsup |g_a(s)|$ identically zero in a small open eet to the left of the abscissa)
Next $f(s)=2^s(\zeta(2s)-h(s))$ and $$h(s)=\sum \frac{1}{n^s}({1/n^s-1/(n+1)^s})$$ with the series easily shown to converge absolutely when $\Re s >0$ hence the claim about analytic continuation until $\Re s >0$ and most likely this can be improved by a similar process
As for zeroes when $\Re s >1/2$ I think that the method of Montgomery in which he shows that the partials of the usual Riemann Zeta $\zeta (s)=\sum n^{-s}$ have zeroes in $\Re s >1$ can be extended here to show that $f(s,a)$ have zeroes in $\Re s >1/2$ too for all large $a$ but that's just a guess

Thanks. I might be an amateur but I will need to digest the first link. As for the last part , maybe a link to Montgomery method ? Also I am still not seeing the reason why g(s) is analytic for Re(s) > 1/3

Are you doing something similar to this first continuation step here ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4622671/roots-and-analytic-continuation-of-ts-sum-n0-ns-n-s-1

The paper by Montgomery is the study Turan memorial edited by Halasz and Erdos

For $g$ one bounds $|n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}|$ by $c_s(n^{-\sigma}-(n+1)^{-\sigma})$ and that is $O(n^{-\sigma-1})$ so actually I was wrong and the continuation is indeed to $\Re s>0$

If I take $s=3$ and compute $1/(n^s * (n+1)^s) - 1/n^{2s}$ I get $- 3/n^7 $ as asymptotic at $\infty$ so again, I am not sure how that $1/3$ is derived formally?

Reading your comment , not sure how you formally arrived at $Re(s) > 0 $ either …

The correct estimate is $\Re s  > 0$ for $g$ since for every $\sigma >0$ one has $(n^{\sigma}-(n+1)^{-\sigma})=O_{\sigma}(n^{-\sigma-1})$ by MVT so $g$ converges absolutely and locally uniformly for $\sigma>0$ as for $|n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}|$ that is estimated by writing it as the integral of $x^{-s-1}$ and putting the absolute value in so getting the integral of $x^{-\sigma-1}$ up to constants depending on $s$ so uniform on compact $s$ sets
